# Matching QOS config from CAT 9300 to 2960XR

Tags: qos

I am not familiar with the 2960XR syntax. I need help in matching my current QoS config that is currently on the Cisco 9300 to a cisco 2960XR. Thank you.
The QoS config is of HQoS and follows:

```
BRS-TC-SW-01#show policy-map
    Policy Map CHILD
    Class COS_Q3
          priority level 1
          police rate percent 20
          conform-action transmit
          exceed-action drop
    Class COS_Q2
          bandwidth remaining 57 (%)
    Class COS_Q1
          bandwidth remaining 29 (%)
    Class COS_Q0
          bandwidth remaining 14 (%)
    
Policy Map PARENT
    Class class-default
         Average Rate Traffic Shaping
             cir 120000000 (bps)
             service-policy CHILD

Policy Map system-cpp-policy
    Class system-cpp-police-ios-routing
    police rate 13000 pps
    conform-action transmit
```

Comment: Please don’t use images as opposed to text. You can paste the text directly into your post (using the proper formatting).

Comment: @JesseP. Thank you so much, I am sorry for adding an image.

Comment: The 2K switches use port-based QoS, not the VLAN-based QoS of the 9K switches.

Comment: Are you saying that the QOS configuration from the 9300 cannot be matched on the 2k switches?